# CakePHP site not working after installing PayPal plugin - where do I start?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

My CakePHP site was working fine until yesterday, when I uploaded the PayPal plugin from https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Paypal-IPN-Plugin.

It still works fine locally, but the live site now doesn't work at all - I just get an error saying

> The connection was reset
>
> The connection to the server was reset while
>   the page was loading.

If I remove the plugin name from the helpers array in AppController.php

```
var $helpers = array('Html','Form','PaypalIpn.Paypal')
```

then it works ok again.

I don't really know where to start debugging this - I assume it's some kind of clash with PHP libraries or versions or something, but I don't know what to do to find it.  Usually I would comment out stuff and then re-introduce it one line at a time, but I can't figure out a way to do that, because I don't know which file is the 'master' one in the plugin.

What things can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I found an answer here: https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Paypal-IPN-Plugin/issues/19

In `app/Plugin/PaypalIpn/View/Helper/PaypalHelper.php`, change line 34 to:

```
'file' => APP . DS .'Plugin'. DS .'PaypalIpn'. DS .'Config' . DS . 'paypal_ipn_config.php'
```